# Как загрузить Google ReCaptcha v2 отдельно от домена?

Tags: c#, recaptcha

Какие есть варианты подгрузить Google ReCaptcha v2 отдельно от домена ?

Т.е. как это делают все сервисы распознания капч загружая у себя ?

Эту например: http://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

**URL:** http://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

**KEY:** 6Ld2sf4SAAAAAKSgzs0Q13IZhY02Pyo31S2jgOB5

Comment: скорее всего нужно на своем домене запустить рекапчу привязанную к домену и принудительно заменить все необходимые ключи рекапчи из другого места. Я когда-то встречал информацию об этом, но это было слишком много времени назад поэтому не могу ничего конкретного написать. Если цель проходить рекапчу автоматически - тебе достаточно использовать реальный браузер + селениум для контроля браузера + перевод рекапчи в "аудио режим" + АПИ для speech recognition (желательно гугловское, но не обязательно).

Comment: Дальше можешь вырубить реальный браузер попутно вытянув из него куки необходимые для сайта и продолжить работать с сайтом уже адекватным способом. Это самый простой способ автоматического прохождения рекапчи.